# White Screen AngularApp Deploy on iOS with Cordova

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, cordova

White Screen (Angular App not loaded) by building and running an Angular app with cordova on iOS. I changed the base href to "./" and for a new angular app project everything is running fine.
Running my project on android and browser is also working. What can happen on iOS that my app is not loading?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the white screen:

"Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control_Allow-Origin" this can be solved by installing the plugin https://github.com/globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr